# Button On X & Y coordinates of Image

Tags: android

I am trying to place a button dynamically on an Image when a user touches it.
Can someone help.

I've tried this code but every time the button gets disappeared

```
 rl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            x = rl.getX();
            y=rl.getY();

            int i = x.intValue();
            int j = y.intValue();
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(i,j);
            rd1.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
x=(int)event.getx();
y=(int)event.gety();
```

and set these x,y values to your layout params